# Show that basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$ is (1, j)

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm trying to understand this section: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#:~:text=Quaternions%20can%20be%20represented%20as,as%20pairs%20of%20real%20numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#:%7E:text=Quaternions%20can%20be%20represented%20as,as%20pairs%20of%20real%20numbers).

One of the things they claim is that the basis of $$\mathbb{C}^2$$ is (1, j).

For real numbers, to prove that the standard basis vectors are a basis for $R^4$, we would say: for a vector [a,b,c,d], we can always decompose the vector into a*[1, 0, 0, 0] + b*[0, 1, 0, 0] ...

To show that (1, j) is a basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$, we would first have to define some arbitrary vector, analogous to  how we defined [a,b,c,d] above for the real case, in $\mathbb{C}^2$ using variables, and then analogously show that we can decompose that vector into $(a+bi)*1 + (c+di)*j$.

But what is that arbitrary vector? How do we show that (1,j) makes sense as a basis (compared to, for example, [1,0] and [0, 1]) without making circular arguments?

Answer (score 1):

There is no circular argument; the natural argument is that given an *arbitrary* quaternion vector $a+bi+cj +dk $, where $1,i,j,k$ are the standard quaternion basis vectors, then from the identity $ij=k$ we simply obtain
$$a+bi+cj+dk=(a+bi)\cdot 1+(c+di)\cdot j\,,$$
which gives a canonical identification of quaternions with $\mathbb{C}^2$—— that is, $(a,b,c,d)\leftrightarrow(a+bi,c+di)$. You can then identify $(1,0)\in \mathbb{C}^2$ with the quaternion $1$ and $(0,1)\in \mathbb{C}^2$ with the quaternion $j$.

Comment: Why does it naturally make sense that a pair of complex numbers should be represented as $a + bi + cj + dk$?

Comment: It doesn’t make _sense_ that way; it is the identity $ij=k$ that makes it natural that way. There are actually countless ways to represent the quaternions as bi-complex numbers beside the canonical one above.